# Set Interval doesnt update price on my UI (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs

I have this code here to setInterval to update the price every second on my react site:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Coin.css'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Coin extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            price: this.props.price 
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        const callback = () => {
            //set the state to a new random value
            const randomPercentage = 0.995 + Math.random() * 0.01;
            // Dont do this:
            // this.state.price = this.state.price * randomPercentage:

            this.setState(function(oldState){
                return {
                    price: oldState.price * randomPercentage
                };
            });
        }
        setInterval(callback, 1000);  
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <tr className="coin-row">
                <td>{this.props.name}</td>
                <td>{this.props.ticker}</td>
                <td>${this.props.price}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}

Coin.propTypes = {
    name:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    ticker: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    price: PropTypes.number.isRequired
}
```

When i run this app the price on my site should update every second with some random Number

This is a screenshot of my UI
[image]

When i run it nothing happens- price isnt changing every second and i also get no errors in my console. The only thing that i see is this entry in the console:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
```

Whats wrong here? And how can i fix it?

Here is a screenshot from the tutorial and his code is working
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGioT.jpg

Answer (score 5):

replace

`<td>${this.props.price}</td>` with `<td>${this.state.price}</td>`

Comment: LOLOL missed that